# .htaccess force http for sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https, apache2

I have set up my main site to use https. And I force the user over to https with .htaccess. I use this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However I have a sub domain. That is called `xxx` . It's content is located in `./xxx` .  How can I force `xxx.domain.com` to only use http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on 

#redirect www urls to non-www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# do nothing if sub.domain.com is requested 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#redirect the main domain to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Clear  your browser cache before testing this.